# Does react re render everything when we go to a new link?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router

I am currently creating a react app for practice. I am curious does react render everything when we go to a new link? For eg. These are my routers

```
<Route exact path="/" component={AuthenticatedUser(Books)}></Route>
<Route exact path="/librarians" component={AuthenticatedUser(Librarians)}></Route>
```

And my Higher Order Component AuthenticatedUser is as follows:

```
function AuthenticatedUser(Component) {
  return function AuthenticatedComponent({ ...props }) {
    const classes = useStyles();
    return confirmUserAuthencition() ? (
      <>
        <SideMenu />
        <Header />
        <div className={classes.appMain}>
          <PageHeader></PageHeader>
          <Component {...props}></Component>
        </div>
      </>
    ) : (
      <Redirect to="/login" />
    );
  };
}
```

I am just curious, when I go from "/" link to "/librarians", do components SideMenu and Header rerender?

Comment: I think yes in this case. If you want to avoid that, you can place them outside [`Switch` or any wrapper](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Switch) & it will be cheaper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React re-renders on state change. 
From: https://www.educative.io/edpresso/how-to-force-a-react-component-to-re-render

> React components automatically re-render whenever there is a change in their state or props. A simple update of the state, from anywhere in the code, causes all the User Interface (UI) elements to be re-rendered automatically.

These changes can come from setState, useState, and/or forceUpdate calls

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the element that redirects you to the new link. If you use react router's `<Link to="/librarians">` then no, React will not re-render. However, if you use the standard html `<a href="/librarians">` then it will.

Comment: Done the same. but still every time I change a menu, all the api calls from header are getting recalled when I switch the route to route from menu.

Answer (score 0):

No, if you're moving from  `/` to `/librarians` path, your `<SideMenu />` and `<Header />` won't re-render. React uses `virtual DOM` to do the updates on `actual DOM` (`virtual DOM` is a copy of the `actual DOM` and it can do the updates without affecting `actual DOM`)

During reconcilation process, react compares virtual and actual dom and then do the updates on actual dom based on the nodes that are changed.

In your case, since you're not completely removing `AuthenticatedUser` component when redirection, it won't re-render `<SideMenu />` and `<Header />` components that are included in `AuthenticatedUser` component as childs. But `AuthenticatedUser` re-render itself since you're changing the passed `Component` prop.

In order identify this properly you can put a `console.log` in `<SideMenu />` and `<Header />` to check whether re-render themselves when moving from `/` to `/librarians`.

Comment: I actually did put console.log in useeffect hook, with empty array as dependancy list, in sidemenu and header component. Actually It does re-render.

Answer (score 0):

Since your HOC's return statement depends on the value of the confirmUserAuthencition(), we can't always say whether or not the  and  components will get re-rendered.

The DOM will stay unaffected as long as the user remains authenticated or unauthenticated. The two components need not be re-rendered each time this route is hit in this case.

Answer (score 0):

React won't re-render the entire page unnecessarily. It will only re-render all components except the SideMenu and Header component.

You may find this article helpful in understanding how react re-renders - [Article](https://felixgerschau.com/react-rerender-components/)

Answer (score 0):

It will re-render any component that has changed, as determined by `shouldComponentUpdate()` for each component

In your case, if you're navigating to the new page via menu navigation, it will re-render the final component, as well as the nav-menu. Depending on your implementation, it's quite likely that the it will re-render the whole AuthenticatedUser component.

Here's the component lifecycle docs:

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate